# Write and Read NFCTag password protected?

Tags: android, mod-rewrite, nfc

is there any way to read and write tag with password protected, the main intention behind for this is,

I want to write message in NFC Tag only from my application, not other application do write operation on this NFC Tag,

we will allow to read all other device and application to read this NFC message, I am using right now like.

```
NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecordArr);
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(myTag);
ndef.connect();
ndef.writeNdefMessage(ndefMessage);
ndef.close();
```

is there any way to add password in write operation?
Thanks.

Comment: Password protection is very specific to the Tag hardware, what make a model is the Tag? If it supports password protection/authentication the it should be possible.

Comment: For an NTAG216 I wrote a sample app to write protect the Tag: https://github.com/MichaelsPlayground/NfcNfcaAuthProtection/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/androidcrypto/nfcnfcaauthprotection/SetWriteProtectionActivity.java

Comment: Okay thanks, let me check and inform you.

Comment: I try with password protected NfcA, MifareUltraligh, NdefFormatable device, but it will give error like IoException : Transceive failed

Comment: @MichaelFehr i can not figure it out, can u pls help me?

Comment: I think my Nfc device is NXP - NTAG213, am I missing something.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lv42A83tP9kMOSGtFN5mDC6lT3yfi07u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I wrote the "setWriteProtection" for a very similar (but larger) NTAG216, so you need to adopt the pages where the write protection bit and bytes are written. Kindly download the data sheet for NTAG21x - there you find the addresses for NTAG213 tags and it should be very easy to adopt my code. "*i can not figure it out*" - what code have you written so far ?

Comment: I need little help from your side if you have a time, i have some confusion on read/write MifareUltralight tag

Comment: the official document say it will write on page wise, and each page contain 4 byte only?

Comment: also first 4 page (16 byte) for the security and other 4 page (16 byte) for the data

Comment: right now I stuck on this part, currently I have done some code for read/write from this reference https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#read-write

Comment: i am not able to add security to write (Password Protection) in this